# Calculating process efficiency for a process with inconsistent yeilds

Tags: statistics

This related to programming, but the question at hand is purely a mathematical/statistical one

I being ask to display an efficiency of a process over a set period of time. Normally not a an issue, this process should produce $X$ qty a minute, over time $T$, $Y$ parts were made, therefore, the efficiency formula I use would be
$$
E = \frac{Y}{(X*T)}
$$

My problem stems from the fact that this process has a variable rate. So for a length of time $H_1$ it might have a qty/min of $X$, then for length of time $Z$ have a rate of 0, then for time $H_2$ have a qty/min of $W$.

if I want to consider the time frame $Z$ to be **0%** efficient, how would I best go about calculating an overall efficiency for the time frame of $H_1+H_2+Z$

because
$$
E = \frac{Y_1+Y_2+0}{(X*H_1)+(W*H_2)+(0*Z)}
$$

would give the same answer whether $Z$ was 30sec or 30days.

Comment: The length of time the process is turned off is irrelevant as nothing is expected to be produced then and presumably nothing is, so the length of time it is turned off does not affect the actual / expected ratio

Comment: That is not true at all.  When the process is off, it is not making money, if it is running, it does. so I'm trying to form some way of representing that lost opportunity. Unless you think running a machine for 1 hour a day is 'efficient'

Comment: If you think it should be producing when off, then you should not say "for length of time $Z$ have a rate of $0$".  Change that $0$ for what you think it should have been producing at that time and your problem will be solved as $Z$ will have an impact on the calculation